# Save "unseen" output of command to file

Tags: logs, filter

I have a program that returns some content every time I run it. Some of that content may have already shown during the last run.

```
foo
bar
baz
```

and on next execution it might show two "old lines" and one "new line":

```
bar
baz
house
```

Is it possible to filter out and save previously unseen content of these commands to a file, so that I end up with

```
foo
bar
baz
house
```

Note that I run this command very irregularly, so there may be minutes up to days between two executions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `sponge` from the `moreutils` package installed:

```
$ printf '%s\n' foo bar baz > log                                    # first call
$ printf '%s\n' bar baz house | grep -v -F -x -f log | sponge -a log # subsequent calls
$ cat log
foo
bar
baz
house
```